# PHP - can't call for function inside double quotes

Tags: php, string, double-quotes

I have a PHP code:

```
class Test {
    function someThing(){ return 1}
}

$test = new Test();

//why this isn't printing bla bla bla 1????
echo "bla bla bla $test->someThing()";
```

but it seems like I can't call function inside a double quoted string.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot, unless you use eval(), which is usually a bad idea. You'd have to get the function call outside of the string.

Comment: ive updated the question to show i need to print some words + return values of a fucntion

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can only call variables inside a string

but if you use {} you can add code to the block

try this:

```
echo "bla bla bla {$test->someThing()}";
```

Comment: That only apply to member variables (with arrow `->`), global function can't.

Answer (score 5):

You can also put a function name inside a variable and then use that variable like a real function inside double quotes string:

```
$arr = [1,2,3];
$func_inside_var = 'implode';
echo "output: {$func_inside_var($arr)}" . '<br>';
```

Note that you can even pass paramater to that call.

Comment: This is good to know, but doesn't actually answer the question. Merry Winter Bash!

Answer (score 3):

Try this way

```
class Test {
    function someThing()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

$test = new Test();

echo 'bla bla bla ' . $test->someThing();
```

Comment: And where's the other part of the string?

Answer (score 0):

you should use this

```
echo "".$test->someThing()."";
```

or with out double quoted.

```
echo $test->someThing();
```